# Pip installs outdated libraries when I create a new Docker container

Tags: python, docker, pip, python-requests

I need to test a Docker named [bibbox/app-galakasio](https://github.com/bibbox/app-galaksio/tree/5f0482c531dd7a9d1369b07c2b2ce978acf39312) debugging purposes (link goes to Github repository). It is very similar to another docker available [fikipollo/galaksio](https://github.com/fikipollo/galaksio/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile) with the important distinction that only the second one works due to issues with dependencies.

The code for installing dependencies are as far as I can tell identical

```
#INSTALL THE DEPENDENCIES

RUN apt-get update  \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y wget libapache2-mod-wsgi 
    python-flask python-requests unzip python-pip \
    && apt-get clean \
    && pip install bioblend \
    && pip install fpdf
```

fikipollo/galaksio installs Bioblend 0.10.0 which is outdated but contains a snippet to solve a bug in python-requests while bibbox/app-galaksio installs Bioblend 0.11.0 which has removed the snippet as it is no longer needed. Both dockers however installs requests 2.4.3 which is old (and contains the bug). So downgrading bibbox/app-galaksio to 0.10.0 makes it work but what I want to do is to make sure that both dockers run up to date packages. But so far I've been unable to make pip upgrade to up-to-date versions of python requests which is what I need help with.

Comment: I noticed you're installing `python-requests` with `apt-get`. What happens if you instead try installing `requests` through `pip`?

Comment: what pip version are u using? you can see that using pip --version

Comment: have you tried:  ```pip install bioblend==0.11.0```? Also, might want to make sure you install the latest version of pip.

Comment: @Sp0gg, there was a version conflict when updating pip so it took some time but deleting it and reinstalling it without using apt-get solved the problem. Upgrading python-requests then solved the problem.

Comment: @MichaelKarotsieris pip is version 1.5.6.

Comment: @lwileczek, it is the opposite as the workaround is removed in Bioblend 0.11.0. But setting it to bioblend==0.10.0 is my workaround until I can understand why apt-get downloads outdated versions of python-pip and python-requests.

Comment: the latest pip version is 10.x.x afaik so you have a very outdated version. Try install the latests pip as: pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing `requests` through `pip` rather than `python-requests` through `apt`. PyPI should be more up-to-date than apt.